# How to get string length in qmake

Tags: string, qmake, string-length, variable-length

Lets say we have a variable `VAR` in a qmake pro file. How to get the VAR content length? I tried to use bash syntax `{#$VAR}`.

Comment: For anything complicated, calling an external script may make sense (with the string passed, potentiallt quoted). You can check the docs for the `env()` (or whatever its name is) qmake func allowing to do that. Another way is qmake-post-link (don't remember the spelling now, probably has some undesrcores inside), allowing to do the same, essentially, just at somewhat dufferent stages. That's all I know :)